# Incorrect user-agent displayed when using window.navigator - does not match http header

Tags: javascript, angular, user-agent, user-agent-switcher

I switch user-agent using the chrome extention and here is the user-agent string in the http header: [image]

Here is a console log of the window.navigator.userAgent. why aren't they the same? How can I programmatically  get the userAgent shown in the http header in Javascript or Angular? [image]

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the "user-agent switcher for chrome" extention, I changed the " user agent " in the network conditions tab in the chrome inspector. that worked: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/override-user-agent/